# SwiftUI typing causes unwanted behavior

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a basic login UI. I have a email field and a password field then a login button at the bottom. With iOS 16 this was not a problem.

But now with iOS 17 for some reason every time I input a character from the keyboard into only the email field then the log in button jitters up and down. If I enter a char into the password field which is identical this doesn't happen. If I remove the password field then the problem goes away. It seems like having 2 of these fields in the same stack is doing something weird.

```
import SwiftUI

struct LogInView: View {
    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top){
            VStack {
                VStack(spacing: 15){
                    CustomTextField(imageName: "envelope", placeHolderText: "Email", text: $email)
                    CustomTextField(imageName: "lock", placeHolderText: "Password", isSecureField: true, text: $password)
                }.padding(.horizontal, 32)
            }.padding(.top, 20).ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack(spacing: 1){
                Spacer()
                Button {

                } label: {
                        Text("Sign in")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                            .background(.systemOrange).opacity(0.7))
                            .clipShape(Capsule())
                            .padding()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomTextField: View {
    let imageName: String
    let placeHolderText: String
    var isSecureField: Bool? = false
    @Binding var text: String
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Image(systemName: imageName)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                .foregroundColor((colorScheme == .dark) ? .white : .gray)
            
            if isSecureField ?? false {
                SecureField(placeHolderText, text: $text)
                    .tint((colorScheme == .dark) ? .white : .black)
                    .focused($isFocused)
            } else {
                TextField(placeHolderText, text: $text)
                    .tint((colorScheme == .dark) ? .white : .black)
                    .focused($isFocused)
            }
        }
        .padding(.vertical, 12)
        .padding(.horizontal, 5)
        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: isFocused ? 2 : 1))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noticed, the issue seem to be related at the order in which the textfields are placed. If we place the TextField before the SecureField the bouncy behavior will me more pronounced. I thought of various solutions here, on of them involved using an offset in y to render the SecureField before the TextField and then offset them to place the TextField as the first, but for some reason, the bouncy behavior was the same as if we placed the TextField before the SecureField... Another experiment I tired was to use the UIKit SecureField using the UIViewRepresetable protocol. That seems to reduce the bouncy effect. So here's the code:

```
struct LogInView: View {
    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    @FocusState private var activeTF: ActiveKeyboardField!
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) private var colorScheme
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center){
            VStack {
                VStack(spacing: 15){
                    
                    HStack {
                        
                        Image(systemName: "lock")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                            .foregroundColor((colorScheme == .dark) ? .white : .gray)
                        
                        SecureUIKitField(password: $password)
                            .tint((colorScheme == .dark) ? .white : .black)
                            .focused($activeTF, equals: .password)
                            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: activeTF == .password ? 2 : 1))
                            .onTapGesture {
                                activeTF = .password
                            }
                    }
                    .frame(height: 45)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    //.offset(y: 62)
                    
                    HStack{
                        Image(systemName: "envelope")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                            .foregroundColor((colorScheme == .dark) ? .white : .gray)
                        
                        TextField("Email", text: $email)
                            .tint((colorScheme == .dark) ? .white : .black)
                            .focused($activeTF, equals: .email)
                            .padding(.vertical, 12)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: activeTF == .email ? 2 : 1))
                            .onTapGesture {
                                activeTF = .email
                            }
                            .scrollDismissesKeyboard(.never)
                    }
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    //.offset(y: -62)
                    .onAppear {
                        activeTF = .email
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 32)
            }
            .padding(.top, 20)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .onChange(of: activeTF) { newValue in
                guard let newValue else { return }
                print("Old value: \(activeTF!)")
                print("New value: \(newValue)")
                activeTF = newValue
            }
            
            VStack(spacing: 1){
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    
                } label: {
                    Text("Sign in")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                        .background(.orange).opacity(0.7)
                        .clipShape(Capsule())
                        .padding()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

enum ActiveKeyboardField {
    
    case email
    case password
    
}

struct SecureUIKitField: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var password: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let secureField = UITextField()
        secureField.isSecureTextEntry = true
        secureField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        secureField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return secureField
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = password
        uiView.placeholder = "Password"
    }
    
}
```

I avoided the ifs as you mentioned, but the issue wasn't even that. Something buggy is going on when placing TF before a SF. You can play with those offset I put. I've left theme there.
Let me know :)

Comment: Thanks I replaced my **CustomTextField** with the new **CustomTextField** you provided and I still face the same issue. When using one of these by its self this doesn't happen but did you use 2 of these structs in a stack as my question indicates?

Comment: Actually that wasn't the issue. If I flip the fields and put the password field above the email one then nothing happens. But if I put the email field on top then typing causes the same bug. I have no idea whats going on. But I don't think the focus state is the problem though because I encounter the same issue with it removed.

Comment: Seems like there's an issue with using a normal textfield above a secure field, the .focusable modifier from this thread didn't work, do you have any idea how I could fix this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73277582/swiftui-view-with-textfield-and-securefield-buggy-on-macos-shows-strange-view

Comment: I should give it a look. Maybe I have some ideas.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Give it a try but, be aware it is not completly solved.

Comment: I've found a similar issue here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73755705/focusstate-changes-in-swiftui-cause-the-keyboard-to-bounce/77844714#77844714